# Not able to route some sites with ejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I'm working on my side structure and tried to add multiple single pages.

Here is my site structure:

```
bin
node_modules
public
query
routes
- index.js

views
-menu
--menu1.ejs
--menu2.ejs
--menu3.ejs

-partials
--header.ejs

-index.js
-anzeige.js
-eintragen.js
```

I tried to route the sites in my index.js like this:

```
//works
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  console.log('Request for index recieved');
  res.render('index');
});

//works
router.get('/menu1', (req, res) => {
  console.log('Request for menu1 page recieved');
  res.render('menu/menu1');
});

//not working
router.get('/menu2', (req, res) => {
  console.log('Request for menu2 page recieved');
  res.render('menu/menu2');
});

//not working
router.get('/menu3', (req, res) => {
  console.log('Request for menu3 page recieved');
  res.render('menu/menu3');
});

//works
router.get('/anzeige', (req, res) => {
  console.log('Request for anzeige page recieved');
  res.render('anzeige');
});
```

I also added `index.js` to my `app.js` as a route but somehow my console says me that menu2 and menu3 can't be found (`error 500 internal server error`).

```
Request for menu2 page recieved
GET /menu2 500 7.958 ms - 305
GET http://localhost:3000/menu2 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Additionally my `app.js`, which first creates const routes and implents it afterwards with `app.use('/', routes);`

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');

//Place routes here
//var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
const routes = require('./routes');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

//add routes here
app.use('/', routes);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

menu2.ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
<head>
<title>Speiseplan anzeige</title>
<%- include('partials/header') %>
</head>

<body class="mainContainer">
  <div class="midContainer">
    <h1>menu2</h1>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Am I missing something? It's a bit strange that some sites work and some not.

Comment: use ```../partials/header``` in menu2.ejs instead of ```partials/header```

Comment: can you explain, you are rendering "index" & "anzeige", in particular routes but i don't see index.ejs & anzeige.ejs files in views. also without index.ejs how your index route is working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem found - here the soultion for everyone with the some problem.

As Rajan mentioned I should use `../partials/header` instead of `partials/header`.

This worked for me and everything is now displayed perfectly.

Thank you all!